# How to view exception trace in winform

Tags: winforms, exception, logging, stack-trace, viewer

I want to view stack trace as the given window. I'm writing my own log viewer. Is there any way to get this window as it is in visual studio.

thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's just a standard property grid control.

Comment: I don't think so. For example, in a standard property grid control, false is spelled False, it does not shows "null", etc... It's VS debugger locals/watch control. And if you push an exception into a property grid, you will not have all this.

Comment: You may be right that it's not just a property grid, but a property grid will give you everything you see there.

Comment: That's not correct. For, example TargetSite and InnerException are not expandable. Or we're not talking about System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.